# how to install php5-memcached in linux?

Tags: linux, debian, php5, memcached

I've installed memcached server using yum. My server os info -

```
Linux version 3.8.4-x86_64-linode31 (maker@build) (gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8) ) #1 SMP Mon Mar 25 16:00:34 EDT 2013
```

But when i try to install php5-memcached using yum, it says - 
    No package php5-memcached available.

Then i've tried using apt-get, but it says, apt-get command not found
    sudo: apt-get: command not found

Now, how can i install php5-memcached in my server?

Thanks

Comment: Yum will work on redhat, apt-get on Debian. Your question is confusing, are you sure that's correct?

Comment: I've CentOS, yum works there(sorry, apt-get command wont work there i guess)

Comment: You have "debian" in tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RHEL or CentOS, you need to have the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository enabled. When it is enabled you can install the php memcached package with the following command

```
yum install php-pecl-memcached
```

Comment: I've CentOS, tried your command but it says `Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-pecl-memcached available.` but if i try php-pecl-memcache, that is available.

Comment: Btw, i'm trying now using pecl, using command `pecl install memcached`, lets see how its come

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **Debian** then check if /usr/bin is in your path by doing `echo $PATH`. If not you can fix you path or run apt-get directly by specifying the full path `/usr/bin/apt-get php5-memcached`

Answer (score 0):

1. search package

> $ sudo yum search memcached

```
ea-php70-php-memcached.x86_64 : php-memcached extension for ea-php70
ea-php70-php-memcached-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package ea-php70-php-memcached
ea-php71-php-memcached.x86_64 : php-memcached extension for ea-php71
ea-php71-php-memcached-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package ea-php71-php-memcached
ea-php72-php-memcached.x86_64 : php-memcached extension for ea-php72
ea-php72-php-memcached-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package ea-php72-php-memcached
...............................
```

2. install according to your PHP version
   , I have php 7.2, so I chose

> $ sudo yum install ea-php72-php-memcached

and all done!

Hope this helps

Comment: Use of cPanel is [not supported](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094/126632) at this site.